# Django URL pattern to manage creation and update in the same view - NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm facing a 'NoReverseMatch' error that I'm not able to solve, even if I'm quite convinced it's probably a stupid error, something I missed... as I reproduce a pattern I successfully implemented earlier in the same app.
The context is the following: I have the same view for creating and updating an object. The difference is that in the second case, I have the id. Thus, related urls look like this (I put the whole file to ensure there is no mismatch with other urls):

```py
app_name = "polls"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("get_chart_data/", views.get_chart_data, name="chart_data"),
    path("set_proxy/", views.set_proxy, name="set_proxy"),
    path("accept_proxy/", views.accept_proxy, name="accept_proxy"),
    path("cancel_proxy/", views.cancel_proxy, name="cancel_proxy"),
    path("sign_up/", views.new_user, name="sign_up"),
    path("login/", views.login_user, name="login"),
    path("logout/", views.logout_user, name="logout"),

    path("<slug:comp_slug>/", views.company_home, name="company_home"),

    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_users/", views.adm_users, name="adm_users"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_load_users/", views.adm_load_users, name="adm_load_users"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_profile/", views.adm_user_profile, name="adm_create_user"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_profile/<int:usr_id>", views.adm_user_profile, name="adm_user_profile"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/change_password/", views.change_password, name="change_password"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_delete_user/<int:usr_id>", views.adm_delete_user, name="adm_delete_user"),

    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_events/", views.adm_events, name="adm_events"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_create_event/", views.adm_event_detail, name="adm_create_event"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_update_event/<int:evt_id>/", views.adm_event_detail, name="adm_event_detail"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_delete_event/<int:evt_id>", views.adm_delete_event, name="adm_delete_event"),

    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_groups/", views.adm_groups, name="adm_groups"),

    # ===== THE 2 FOLLOWING LINES ARE THE ISSUE  =====
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_group_detail/", views.adm_group_detail, name="adm_create_group"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_group_detail/<int:grp_id>/", views.adm_group_detail, name="adm_group_detail"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_delete_group/<int:grp_id>", views.adm_delete_group, name="adm_delete_group"),

    path("<slug:comp_slug>/admin_options/", views.adm_options, name="adm_options"),

    path("<slug:comp_slug>/<slug:event_slug>/", views.event, name="event"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/<slug:event_slug>/<int:question_no>", views.question, name="question"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/<slug:event_slug>/<int:question_no>/vote", views.vote, name="vote"),
    path("<slug:comp_slug>/<slug:event_slug>/results", views.results, name="results"),
]
```

The pattern is the same for users management (`adm_user_profile` view) with no issue.
Here is the view:

```py
def adm_group_detail(request, comp_slug, grp_id=0):
    company = Company.get_company(comp_slug)
    if grp_id > 0:
        current_group = EventGroup.objects.get(id=grp_id)
        group_form = GroupDetail(request.POST or None, instance=current_group)
    else:
        group_form = GroupDetail(request.POST or None)
        group_form.fields['all_users'].queryset = UserComp.objects.\
                                                    filter(company=company).\
                                                    order_by('user__last_name', 'user__first_name')


    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Some dedicated code I could add if necessary, the problem is for GET request

    return render(request, "polls/adm_group_detail.html", locals())
```

The view is called thanks to a button, here is related HTML code:

```html
<div class="text-center">
    <!-- Create button -->
    <a type="button" class="create-grp btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'polls:adm_create_group' company.comp_slug %}">Nouveau groupe</a>
</div>
```

The error message is:

```
Reverse for 'adm_group_detail' with arguments '('impuls-ions',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<comp_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/admin_group_detail/(?P<grp_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Tracebacks points out `return render()` statement, and I see no problem with local variables:

```
Variable    Value
________________________________
comp_slug   'impuls-ions'
company     <Company: Impuls'Ions>
group_form  <GroupDetail bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(group_name;weight;users;all_users;group_list)>
grp_id      0
request     <WSGIRequest: GET '/impuls-ions/admin_group_detail/'>
```

Comment: Can you please show us the section where you call `admin_group_detail` url in the template ? The issue is about it i think

Comment: It's exactly the part of HTML code I shared

Comment: The url pattern requires two arguments. You must pass to reverse both comp_slug and grp_id

Comment: @HåkenLid you're right for updating a group, not for creating a new one, I'm I wrong?

Comment: When you declare your url patterns, you use the name `adm_create_group` for the create route. Pass that to reverse instead of `adm_detail_view`. Both routes can use the same django view function. The route names are what matters for reverse, not the name of the view function.

Comment: @Christophe I mean the section where you have the update link  like : `href="{% url 'polls:adm_group_detail' company.comp_slug company.id %}"`

Comment: @Rvector would you want me to share the whole HTML code? The part I share is in its own div, and I do not know what you would like to check

Comment: @HåkenLidthere is no `adm_detail_view` in my pattern, I'm not sure to understand what you mean, or what you suggest I should change

Comment: @HåkenLid just to be sure, which case are you talking about? Int the HTML, the reverse route is defined like this: `{% url 'polls:adm_create_group' company.comp_slug %}` so I do not understand what you had in mid when you talk about `adm_detail_view`, could you please precise?

Comment: It's in your error message. The one in your question. Read the error message. And read the traceback as well. It's important to read the traceback. The traceback contains the information you need to debug this. That's why you should include the full traceback when seeking help with debugging. But you should read the traceback yourself as well. It will help you find the source of your bug. traceback.

Comment: I fully agree with you and usually I can find the solution with the Traceback. Anyway, thanks for highlighting this specific point, the problem was not in the view, nor the HTML, but the destination HTML page. To validate the form, I actually wrote et wrong url name, so he was not able to reverse the url, which led to this error. Many thanks again